# How to appen early message at top of GiftedChat?

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, react-native

Guys I only find GiftedChat.append function available to add new message to it. It works well for new incoming messages because they are usually display at the bottom og list. However, we need to early messages goes to top of list. But append function couldn't work for this situation. Does any one knows how to work out this one.

Comment: add alignTop props into gifted chat

Comment: It is not working. I guess if giftedchat will reorder incoming messages automatically based on message's created_at?

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded GiftChat Demo Code. And I found out that I need to use prepend rather than append to add old messages into list. Append will add msgs to bottom of list. Prepend will add msgs to top of list.